# Return or create a token if the user already exist? django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, access-token

Is posible to return or create a token if the user already exists?
I need something like this

```
class LoginEasy(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        pw = '!Rd5tkis-02kjWk'
        serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            u = User.objects.filter(email=serialized.data['email'])
            if len(u) > 0:
                userdata= {'id': u[0].id, 'password': pw,  'first_name': u[0].first_name, 'last_name': u[0].last_name, 'email': u[0].email},
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=userdata)
                return Response({'token': token.key,
                                 'id': userdata.id,
                                 'first_name': userdata.first_name,
                                 'last_name': userdata.last_name,
                                 'email': userdata.email})
```

**I'm getting this error.**

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

Comment: What does the Token model definition look like? Also getting attributes from a dictionary will not work the way you have implemented it. For example, first_name will be accessible through userdata['first_name']

Comment: Hi, I think I resolved the problem...

I used user = User.objects.get(username=serialized.data['email']) instead of             user = User.objects.filter(username=serialized.data['email'])

but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

your model `Token` need for correct answer, but i think you need

```
Token.objects.get_or_create(**userdata)
#                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and you can do your response more simple:

```
userdata.update({'token': token.key})
return Response(userdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, if this could help somebody here is the fixed code.

```
def post(self, request):
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        u = User.objects.filter(email=serialized.data['email'])
        user = User.objects.get(username=serialized.data['email'])
        if len(u) > 0:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: User.objects.get(username=serialized.data['email']) is not a good idea. If User object does not exist, this will throw an exception and crash your code

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will try to handle a reponse for that. Thanks @arjun27